# Create item test is failing despite the functionality working in the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test with failing despite knowing the functionality works in the app.  My instinct says that I should try saving the thing that I create but I'm not sure how to do this in the assert_difference block beacause it doesn't look like the new `thing` is assigned to a variable on which I can `.save`. Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Test:

```
test "should create thing" do
    assert_difference('thing.count') do
      post :create, thing: { thing_type_id: @thing.thing_type_id, name: @thing.name}
    end
```

Output:

```
 1) Failure:
test_should_create_thing(thingsControllerTest) [C:/../thing_controller_test.rb:20]:
"thing.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may have some left over state in your database. I see that `expected but was <2>`, meaning you already have two `Thing`s in your DB.

You can try clearing the DB state between tests. Depending on your database check out the [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.

Also, it seems you may have already created the object, by the existence of `@thing`. If that is the case, this is working as expected.

You can take the controller out of the equation to verify this by just testing a normal `Thing::create`:

```
test "creates a new Thing" do
  assert_difference('Thing.count') do
    Thing.create thing_type_id: @thing.thing_type_id, name: @thing.name
  end
end
```